# What is the difference between terminal mode of jupyter-lab and the native terminal

Tags: macos, jupyter-lab

I'm quite confused by the following simple python code:

```py
count = {"a":1}

for key in sorted(count.keys()):
    print(f"{key}:{count[key]}")
```

This code works in the interactive mode of python.
But, when I put it into the file "test.py",
and try to execute as "% python test.py",
in the "terminal" of Jupyter-lab,
I always find the error message as follows :

> File "test.py", line 4
> print(f'{key}:{count[key]}')
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

When I try to execute "test.py" in the machine's native (macos) terminal ,
no error occurs, of course.

What is the difference between two "terminal"'s.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer with my own hands.

In native terminal, python --version gives "Python 3.7.9"

On the other hand, in the termilan of jupyter-lab,
python --version gives "Python 2.7.16".

Maybe, I have failed to install Anaconda correctly.

I hope my experience is useful for resolving similar situations.